# How to implement this with the Java SE 8 Stream API?

Tags: java, java-8

I have tried below code to convert into java8 :

```
List<Value> values = valueRepository.findByCorp(corpId, type, "NONE");
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

  List<Value> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
//This is working code snippet
    values.forEach(v -> {
  for (Product product : products) {
    if (!isEditable(map.get(product.getProductId()), v.getId().getCode()) ||
        "TEST".equals(v.getId().getCode())) {
      continue;
    }
    temList.add(v);
    break;
  }
});



 private boolean isEditable(List<String> list, String type) {
    return list != null && list.size() > 0 && list.contains(type);
  }
```

Here is mine stuff what I have tried so far:

```
    values.forEach(v -> {
        Optional<ProductDTO> findProduct = products.stream().filter(isEditable(map.get(product.getProductId()), v.getId().getCode()) ||
            !"TEST".equals(v.getId().getCode())).findFirst();
            if(findProduct.isPresent()) {
              temList.add(v);
            }
  });
```

But its not working somehow. Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? That code is already Java 8, because `values.forEach(v -> {` isn't valid Java syntax before Java 8. Saying you want to convert Java 8 code to Java 8 makes no sense.

Comment: @Andreas wnat to achieve this feature by java8 stream API

Comment: If you want to use Java 8 *Stream* API, **edit** the question and say so. *"convert into java 8"* sounds like you're converting from another language. Since Java is backwards compatible with earlier versions (for the most part), converting e.g. Java 7 to Java 8 is meaningless, because the Java 7 source code is already fully functioning in Java 8. There is nothing to convert.

Comment: What is not working? Can you share a sample test data to illustrate? There are other unknowns such as `products`, empty `map` which might be more meaningful with the actual context. On a different note, if you `findFirst` and then ignore the actual value, its better to use `anyMatch` I believe.

Comment: Your title it not reflecting the content of your post. It makes it difficult to search.

Comment: @Scratte unable to get you, pelease explain

Comment: I just meant that "How to implement this" does not reflect that you are trying to add items to a list, based on a condition. So even if I have the same issue, I will never find this post.

Answer (score 1):

wrong logical operator used, change `||`  to `&&`:

```
    values.forEach(v -> {
    Optional<ProductDTO> findProduct = products.stream().filter(isEditable(map.get(product.getProductId()), v.getId().getCode()) &&
        !"TEST".equals(v.getId().getCode())).findFirst();
        if(findProduct.isPresent()) {
          temList.add(v);
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

without using **isEditable** function

```
List<Value> tempList = values.stream()
            .filter(v -> v.getId().getCode() != "TEST")
            .filter(v -> products.stream()
                    .map(p -> map.get(p.getProductId()))
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .filter(l -> l.size() > 0)
                    .filter(l -> l.contains(v.getId().getCode()))
                    .findFirst().isPresent())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

Stream the contents of `value` and filter them by comparing each value against all products using your (negated) condition. Your condition was to skip/continue - the same when negated would result in a condition to include a value in the final result.

```
tempList = values.stream()
            .filter(value -> !"TEST".equals(value.getId().getCode())
            .filter(value -> products.stream()
                    .anyMatch(product -> isEditable(map.get(product.getProductId()), 
                            value.getId().getCode()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```